# How to organize MongoDB replicaset backup and alerting

Tags: database-design, replication, backup, mongodb, failover

I have a running MongoDb replicaset consisting of 2 replicas and 1 master nodes. Recently I noticed that my master gone and automatic failover took action and changed master, however I wasn't aware of this. Furthermore, consequently backups are missing for a few days as the mongo service was doen on master and backup was set up only on master.

Obviously this isn't a best practice as I have nor alerts neither proper backups.

I would like to ask couple of things regarding this.

1. Is it fine to set up backups script on all 3 nodes with plain `crontab` and `mongorestore`?
2. How usually alerting is done in this kind of situations when I have to know status of MongoDB (or any other service generally) based on some events like termination or high load?

FYI I leverage MongoDB on AWS EC2 Ubuntu instances.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run backup on all nodes (but rather `mongodump` or `monogexport`). It is just a matter of available disk space.

You can develop your own scripts and check whatever you like, e.g. `systemctl status mongod`, `rs.status()`, `db.hello()`, etc.

Or you use the Mongo [Ops Manager](https://www.mongodb.com/de-de/products/ops-manager)

And then you have standard monitoring tools, one of the most common known is [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/)

Answer (score 0):

It's always recommended to run backup only on the `SECONDARY` nodes. Running backup on primary node will increase the disk IO since we already have heavy writes traffic from the application to the `PRIMARY` node. You can write your own shell/python scripts to configure based on the below logic:

1. Identify whether node in the replica set is `SECONDARY` or not. If the below returns `false` then it's secondary and you can proceed to next step for backup.

> db.hello().isWritablePrimary

2. Run the `mongodump` backup commands,compress the dump file and save it on some location

> mongodump --host hostname --db dbname --archive=/db_backup/dbname.gz
> --gzip

To alert you can try few open source plugins for basic DB health checks: [Mongo Monitor](https://github.com/dwmkerr/mongo-monitor), [Check MongoDB](https://github.com/dalenys/check_mongodb).